# Bash counting Arguments

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-arguments

I am having an issue counting the arguments I enter in my shell script. My script is suppose to echo "You have entered too many arguments" by using and Else statement at the end of my code. If I enter more than 3 I get nothing. Am I missing something simple or should I change this to a case statement. I am new to shell scripting so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

Today=$(date +"%m-%d-%y")
echo -en '\n'
echo "To find out more about this calculator please refer to the calc.readme file."
echo -en '\n'
echo "You entered $*"
echo -en '\n'
if [ "$#" -eq "3" ]; then
if   [ "$2" == "+" ]; then
    answer=`expr $1 + $3`
    echo "You entered the correct amount of arguments"
    echo -en '\n'
    echo "Your total is: "`expr $1 + $3`
    echo "[$Today]: $@ = $answer"  >> calc.history
elif [ "$2" == "-" ]; then
    answer=`expr $1 - $3`
    echo "You entered the correct amount of arguments"
    echo -en '\n'
    echo "Your total is: "`expr $1 - $3`
    echo "[$Today]: $@ = $answer" >> calc.history
 elif [ "$2" == "*" ]; then
    answer=`expr $1 \* $3`
    echo "You entered the correct amount of arguments"
    echo -en '\n'
    echo "Your total is: "`expr $1 \* $3`
    echo "[$Today]: $@ = $answer" >> calc.history
 elif [ "$2" == "/" ]; then
    asnwer=`expr $1 / $3`
    echo "You entered the correct amount of arguments"
    echo -en '\n'
    echo "Your total is: "`expr $1 / $3`
    echo "[$Today]: $@ = $answer" >> calc.history
 else
    echo -en '\n'
    echo "You entered too many arguments."
  fi
  fi
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `else` branch be after the first `fi` ?

Comment: also note you have `asnwer=\`expr $1 / $3\`` in the last `elif` section (there may be others. Try pasting your code into http://shellcheck.net and see what else crops up. Good luck.

Comment: `echo -en '\n'` is a long, non-standard way of writing `echo`.

Comment: Use `answer=$(( $1 + #3))`, etc.,  instead of `expr`. For that matter, you can use `answer=$(( $1 $2 $3))`.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I did have to put the else have the first fi.

Comment: What would be a way to add a blank line between echos besides using ' echo -en '\n' '?

Comment: `echo` already prints a newline at the end of its arguments. `-n` disables that, but then you are explicitly printing a newline. `echo` with no arguments prints a blank line already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your if statements are wrongly nested. You wrote:

```
if <test on number of arguments>
  if <values>
  else
    <wrong number of arguments>
  fi
fi
```

while you should have written:

```
if <test on number of arguments>
  if <values>
  fi
else
  <wrong number of arguments>
fi
```

Comment: Yup. And this is the reason why indentation is so important when writing code. Had OP indented properly he likely wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: Thank you. I will keep indentation in mind. I am use to Netbeans fixing any that I miss.

Answer (score 3):

Your `else` statement is associated with the wrong `if` statement, but you can replace the big `if-elif` chain with a single `case` statement.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

today=$(date +"%m-%d-%y")
echo
echo "To find out more about this calculator please refer to the calc.readme file."
echo
echo "You entered $*"
echo

if [ "$#" -eq "3" ]; then
  echo "You entered the correct amount of arguments"
  case $2 in
    [+-*/])
      echo
      answer=$(( $1 $2 $3 ))
      echo "Your total is $answer"
      echo "[$today]: $@ = $answer" >> calc.history
      ;;
    *) echo "Unrecognized operator $2"
       ;;
  esac
else
  echo
  echo "You entered too many arguments."
fi
```